# ASP.NET page, running two external service calls in parallel

Tags: asp.net, task-parallel-library

I have an asp.net web page that obtains data from two web services, the main one and the fall-back one. Now those services are called consecutively. When running on my box the page render time is usually 6-10 s.
I decided to parellelize those calls so that the fall-back data is available faster if the main service fails.

```
Result res = null;
Task<Result> task = new Task<Result>(() => service1.method1());
task.Start();

res = service2.method();
if(res == null || res.Count == 0)
  res = task.Result;

return res;
```

With that change the page render time grew significantly and reaches 60 s. I added some profiling code and I see that this piece of code typically runs in less than 3 s.
So I suspect that using Tasks somehow hinders the asp.net infrastructure performance.

What might cause that severe performace degradation?
Is there an better way of running those two external service calls in parallel?

Edit 1: I'm mostly interested in the result from service2. The result from service1 will be used only if service2 fails. However, I want to minimize the waiting time for the service1 result if service2 fails.

Comment: Is this 60 s by chance a default service2 timeout so that the code just waits until it fails? You won't easily workaround this othen than setting the timeout to a smaller timespan.

Comment: Nope, the whole method finishes in 3 s or less. That's the tricky thing—the delay seems to happen in a part that has not been changed.

Comment: Mike, I added the answer to your question in Edit 1.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an answer to the question as presented.  Why has service2 failed?  Is it taking 60s regardless of whether it's getting the result from service2 or service1?  Does `res.Count == 0` indicate a failure and not just an empty (but valid) result?  From your profiling, where exactly does the large delay happen?

Comment: Another question -- you're already incurring the overhead of invoking service1.  Does service1 return stale results or some other reason that the result from service1 is not equal in value to the result from service2?

Comment: Mike, the results of service calls are irrelevant here. The whole code block that you see in the question (the only part that I changed) is executed in 3 s or less. The rest of the page code that I have not touched makes the response to come in 60 s.
The result of service2 is actually what I want to show on the page, whereas service1 provides something that is just better than nothing, so that I won't show blank page if service2 fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the code executed within a `Task` called a lazily initialized singleton. The singleton's constructor tried to set up some caching if HttpContext.Current was available. Because HttpContext.Current was not available within a `Task`, the singleton did not use caching and this degraded performance.